# Невестка и сноха

Tags: лексикон, выбор-слова

Есть два русских слова:

**невестка**:

> Замужняя женщина по отношению к родным её мужа: отцу, матери, братьям,
>   сестрам, женам братьев и мужьям сестер.

и **сноха**:

> Женщина по отношению к отцу и матери её мужа, невестка.

По моим наблюдениям, обычно всегда используют слово **невестка**. Как используется слово **сноха** и в чем его отличие от **невестки**?

Comment: Я думаю "сноха" вышла из речевого употребления, "невестка" используется.

Comment: А, например, в Чечне слово "невестка" не используют совсем, а употребляют слова "сноха".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you yourself mentioned in your answer, *сноха* is a narrower term: it means daughter-in-law.

To husband's father and mother a wife is both *невестка* and *сноха* (and some dictionaries even claim that she is a *сноха* only in respect to father-in-law, but not mother-in-law).

To other inlaws (husband's siblings, their spouses; husband's grandparents etc) she is *невестка* (but not *сноха*).

There are two other kinship terms: *ятровь* and *сношенница*, whose usage varies from dialect to dialect. In some dialects, *ятровь* is a synonym for *невестка*; in others it's a stricter term, meaning "brother-in-law's wife". Same for *сношенница*.

Comment: Я знаю слово *сношенница* (это жена деверя). Постоянно путаю его по *свояченницей* (сестрой жены). А вот *ятровь* слышу в первый раз!

Comment: Should I use сноха, or should I forget it? Невестка seems to be universal!

Comment: @ovgolovin: "that woman" is even more universal.

Comment: But "woman" covers a bit wider range of women than "невестка", while "сноха" covers exactly the same set of women as "невестка". So it seems to me that "сноха" is a redundant word.

Comment: @ovgolovin: have you read the answer? *Невестка* is a much wider term.

Comment: For husband's father невестка and сноха cover the same set  of women (all wifes of their sons). So neither of them is wider. Невестка is wider in the terms of the number people this term can be used in respect to (all relatives  of the husband), but this doesn't widen the set of women that are described by this term when the object this term is used in respect to is fixed. So, when сноха is applicable, it is the same as невестка, and невестка is not wider here. It is how I get it.

Comment: I have changed my mind. For a man невестка may mean his son's wife and his brother's wife. While сноха can only mean his son's wife. So yes, невестка is wider, and сноха forms a subset of невесткаs. :o)

Comment: @ovgolovin: what I wanted to say is that these words have different meanings. A woman can be a *невестка* but not *сноха* (just as well as she can be *та баба* but neither a *сноха* nor *невестка*). Both these words are kinship terms which, by definition, require both people they relate to be defined correcly. Compare: *Петрухина-то невестка спилась! Какая невестка, Ленка что-ли? Не, Манька, сноха его. Ленка, та братнина*.

Comment: @ovgolovin: exactly :)

Comment: I just forgot that a father may have other relatives apart from his children, who may have wifes who will be невесткаs for him.

Answer (score 2):

Рисунок, детально поясняющий степени родства:

[image]

Comment: [Он же в лучше качестве, или таком же](http://www.adme.ru/infografika/zanimatelnaya-infografika-433705/433705-5202105/)

Comment: Welcome to Russian Language and Usage Beta! Although your post contains useful information, it does not answer the question. Please edit your post so that it corresponds to the question. Irrelevant answers will be removed. If you wish to add something to another answer, you could invest some time in our site first and earn privileges [to leave comments](http://russian.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) or [to edit answers of other people](http://russian.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit).

Comment: In addition to what Olga indicated, please make sure to actually include your images into the posts.  Linking to external images makes it liable for the post to be broken if those external links go stale.

Answer (score 1):

Цитата из Энциклопедии русского быта:

> ```
>     СВЕКОР – отец мужа. 
>     СВЕКРОВЬ – мать мужа. 
>     ТЕСТЬ – отец жены. 
>     ТЕЩА – мать жены. 
>     ЗЯТЬ: 1) муж дочери; 2) муж сестры. 
>     СНОХА – жена сына по отношению к его отцу, реже – по отношению к его матери. 
>     НЕВЕСТКА: 1) жена брата; 2) жена сына по отношению к его матери, реже – по отношению к его отцу; 3) жена одного брата по отношению к жене другого брата. 
>     ШУРИН – брат жены. 
>     ДЕВЕРЬ – брат мужа. 
>     ЗОЛОВКА – сестра мужа. 
>     СВОЯЧЕНИЦА – сестра жены. 
>     СВОЯК – муж сестры жены. 
>     СВАТ – отец жены сына или мужа дочери. 
>     СВАТЬЯ – мать жены сына или мужа дочери.
> ```

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_rus_mod_of_life_xix/5/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B

Таким образом, если верить уважаемому словарю, то невестка - это жена сына по отношению к матери, а сноха - это жена сына по отношению к отцу.

Лично мне слово "сноха" кажется менее употребляемым, чем слово "невестка", да и вообще в обиходной речи многие, особенно люди помоложе, избегают этих терминов, так как, во-первых, никогда нет полной ясности, кто и что под ними понимает, а во-вторых, они звучат очень обезличенно. Не могу припомнить, чтобы я сама когда-то употребляла слово "сноха" или слышала его от кого-нибудь. Слово "невестка" слышала часто.

Comment: Could you please change your answer so that it answers the question. So far it only gives a lot of information, a major share of which is irrelevant to the question.